# Take out question mark when printing to stdout

Tags: c

I want to take out the question marks. STDIN and STDOUT. but i seem to fail.

```
#define MAXLEN 256
#define widthh argv[2] // fixed 
void wordWrap(int col, char *providedStr);<- my algo for wordWrap

int 
main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int infd, outfd, bytes;
    char buf[MAXLEN];
    int num = atoi(widthh);

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        infd = open(argv[i], O_RDONLY);
        bytes = read(infd, buf, MAXLEN);
       
        if (bytes > 0) {
            wordWrap(num, buf);
        }
        printf("\n"); //just for adding new line to print new file moving forward
    }
}
```

ERROR: 
Learn more about BMW
328i Reliability
Ratings.
?&??? <--- how to get rid of these ?

#### Printing more than one file, ERROR:

The average rating is a 3.9 out of 5 stars. The BMW 328i Reliability Rating is 2.5 out of 5. It ranks 30th out of 32 for all car brands. Learn more about BMW 328i Reliability Ratings.

While these are the similarities of the two cars, the main difference is the horsepower and torque. The BMW 3 Series is faster and more powerful as it comes at 255 horsepower and 295 pounds-feet of torque. With the BMW 4 Series, the horsepower is 248, and pF???

As with the new M4 coupe, the 2021 M3 sedan features a twin-turbo 3.0-liter inline-six. The normal version sends 473 horsepower and 406 pound-feet of torque to the rear wheels. ... Rear-wheel drive is standard, but the Competition will eventually be offerepF???

Comment: Do you realise that `if (EOF)` is always true? `EOF` is `-1`.

Comment: The string has no terminator when passed to `printf()` so it is likely to print junk. Try initialising it with `char buf[MAXLEN] = "";` or with `buf[bytes] = 0;` after the read.

Comment: bro, I'm new to c and I just put that there as an example to show what I'm trying to accomplish. but good to know

Comment: Note that you open each file without closing the previous one.

Comment: @Weather Vane that is my actual code right now. And ?&??? is being printed at the end

Comment: OK, please see my other comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
// you can set max whatever you want for this purpose 1024 is good
#define MAXLEN 1024 
char buf[MAXLEN] = "";
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    infd = open(argv[i], O_RDONLY);
    bytes = read(infd, buf, MAXLEN - 1);
    buf[bytes] = 0;

    if (bytes > 0) {
        wordWrap(num, buf);
    }
    printf("\n"); //just for adding new line to print new file moving forward
}
```

This worked great!
Thank you @Weather Vane

Comment: Then other option `buf[bytes] = 0;` is better, because a string might be shorter than the previous one. But call `read` with `MAXLEN-1` to allow room.

Comment: @Weather Vane wait I was too quick to post that answer, but when I print more files the questions marks come back, and buf[bytes] = 0 would be an integer? no?

Comment: OK please read my previous comment. Note that `'a'` is an integer too.

Comment: MAXLEN-1 does not print the whole string from the file. and I understand what you are saying it does not let me initialize int buf[bytes] = 0; nor my brain is accepting that is even okay to do that. please explain

Comment: Please read carefully: `buf[bytes] = 0;` [*after* the read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66924244/take-out-question-mark-when-printing-to-stdout/66924384?noredirect=1#comment118299035_66924244).